# How do I replace an initialized object?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code which is initiated on page load. It starts a slideshow.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.dothis({
        option:1,
        option:2,
        slides:[
            {image:'img1.jpg'},
            {image:'img2.jpg'}
        ]
    });

});
```

Now I want to add/remove images when the users clicks the body of the page. How do I add/remove items to the slides:[] object? Or how do I replace this object all together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var slideoptions = {
    option:1,
    option:2,
    slides:[
        {image:'img1.jpg'},
        {image:'img2.jpg'}
    ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    $.dothis(slideoptions);

});

// push new image into slides array
slideoptions.slides.push({ 'image' : 'someimg.jpg' });
```

Comment: Could you also tell me how to replace the whole object? I tried without success: slideoptions.slides = [{'image' : 'img3.jpg'}];

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) API to copy one object to another,

```
var slideoptions = {
    option:1,
    option:2,
    slides:[
        {image:'img1.jpg'},
        {image:'img2.jpg'}
    ]
};

var modifiedSlideObj = {   
    option: 4,
    slides: [
        {image:'img3.jpg'},
        {image:'img4.jpg'}
    ]
};

$.extend(slideoptions, modifiedSlideObj);

alert(slideoptions.slides[0].image);
```

Comment: dothis() is using slideoptions for its parameters. Copying another object over this does not have an affect. In other words, dothis() does not use the new parameters.